# Producing Delaunay Triangulations

Tags: tikz-pgf, asymptote

Does anyone know how I can produce 2D Delaunay Triangulations in tikz by giving as inputs a list of randomly generated points? Or at least a program that takes that list and produces tikz output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way of doing it is by following this route: `asy` => `svg` => `TikZ`.

This `d.asy` code from the `Asymptote` docs creates random points 
and builds a triangulation:

```
size(200);
int np=12;
pair[] points;
real r() {return 1.2*(rand()/randMax*2-1);}

srand(1234321);
for(int i=0; i < np; ++i) points.push((r(),r()));

int[][] trn=triangulate(points);
for(int i=0; i < trn.length; ++i) {
  draw(points[trn[i][0]]--points[trn[i][1]]);
  draw(points[trn[i][2]]--points[trn[i][2]]);
  draw(points[trn[i][2]]--points[trn[i][0]]);
}
for(int i=0; i < np; ++i) dot(points[i],red);
```

Generate `d.svg` output with a command:

```
asy -f svg d.asy
```

then convert it to `TikZ` with [svg2tikz](https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz):

```
svg2tikz --standalone d.svg > d.tex
```

Resulting `d.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{cff0000}{RGB}{255,0,0}


\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.80pt,x=0.80pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (39.9691,-90.7908) -- (43.3652,-100.6640);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (43.3652,-100.6640) -- (98.7641,-39.0366);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (98.7641,-39.0366) -- (39.9691,-90.7908);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (80.9286,65.0406) -- (-16.1836,36.7579);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-16.1836,36.7579) -- (98.7641,-39.0366);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (98.7641,-39.0366) -- (80.9286,65.0406);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-16.1836,36.7579) -- (39.9691,-90.7908);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (39.9691,-90.7908) -- (98.7641,-39.0366);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (98.7641,-39.0366) -- (-16.1836,36.7579);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-43.1652,96.4547) -- (-16.1836,36.7579);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-16.1836,36.7579) -- (35.5692,80.1023);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (35.5692,80.1023) -- (-43.1652,96.4547);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-98.9747,37.4920) -- (-48.7898,13.8156);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-48.7898,13.8156) -- (-43.1652,96.4547);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-43.1652,96.4547) -- (-98.9747,37.4920);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-78.9290,-89.2327) -- (-49.1180,-92.8069);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-49.1180,-92.8069) -- (-48.7898,13.8156);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-48.7898,13.8156) -- (-78.9290,-89.2327);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-98.9747,37.4920) -- (-78.9290,-89.2327);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-78.9290,-89.2327) -- (-48.7898,13.8156);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-48.7898,13.8156) -- (-98.9747,37.4920);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (77.7164,83.1456) -- (35.5692,80.1023);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (35.5692,80.1023) -- (80.9286,65.0406);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (80.9286,65.0406) -- (77.7164,83.1456);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (35.5692,80.1023) -- (-16.1836,36.7579);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-16.1836,36.7579) -- (80.9286,65.0406);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (80.9286,65.0406) -- (35.5692,80.1023);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-43.1652,96.4547) -- (-48.7898,13.8156);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-48.7898,13.8156) -- (-16.1836,36.7579);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-16.1836,36.7579) -- (-43.1652,96.4547);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (39.9691,-90.7908) -- (-49.1180,-92.8069);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-49.1180,-92.8069) -- (43.3652,-100.6640);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (43.3652,-100.6640) -- (39.9691,-90.7908);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-43.1652,96.4547) -- (35.5692,80.1023);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (35.5692,80.1023) -- (77.7164,83.1456);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (77.7164,83.1456) -- (-43.1652,96.4547);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-16.1836,36.7579) -- (-48.7898,13.8156);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-48.7898,13.8156) -- (39.9691,-90.7908);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (39.9691,-90.7908) -- (-16.1836,36.7579);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-48.7898,13.8156) -- (-49.1180,-92.8069);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (-49.1180,-92.8069) -- (39.9691,-90.7908);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[draw=black,line join=round,line cap=round,miter limit=10.04,line
      width=0.401pt] (39.9691,-90.7908) -- (-48.7898,13.8156);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (43.3652,-100.6640) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (35.5692,80.1023) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (80.9286,65.0406) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (-49.1180,-92.8069) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (77.7164,83.1456) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (-78.9290,-89.2327) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (39.9691,-90.7908) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (-48.7898,13.8156) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (98.7641,-39.0366) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (-43.1652,96.4547) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (-98.9747,37.4920) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[cm={{1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,(157.101,156.23)}}]
    \path[fill=cff0000] (-16.1836,36.7579) circle (0.0425cm);
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Processing it as usual: `pdflatex d.tex` gives the output:

[image]